# Multiple consecutive groups in one query Mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoid

Here is my working code:

```
age_range = DemographicsData.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { video_id: { '$in' => video_ids }}},
  { '$unwind' => '$demographics_labels' },
  { '$group' => { _id: '$demographics_labels.age_range', count: { '$sum' => 1 }}}
])
gender = DemographicsData.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { video_id: { '$in' => video_ids }}},
  { '$unwind' => '$demographics_labels' },
  { '$group' => { _id: '$demographics_labels.gender', count: { '$sum' => 1 }}}
])
ethnicity = DemographicsData.collection.aggregate([
  { '$match' => { video_id: { '$in' => video_ids }}},
  { '$unwind' => '$demographics_labels' },
  { '$group' => { _id: '$demographics_labels.ethnicity', count: { '$sum' => 1 }}}
])
{
  age: age_range,
  gender: gender,
  ethnicity: ethnicity,
}
```

Is there any way to get the same final result in a single query to the Database?

Mongo v2.4.9

Rails v3.2.8

Ruby v1.9.3

MongoId v3.1.0

Looking forward to upgrading those at some point, but solution would have to take these versions into account.

Comment: If you can update the mongo version to 3.4 then the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) will help you

Comment: I know :( ...soon hopefully